# Where can you download a preview of Xcode 4 from?

Tags: xcode

I can't find any reference to it from the Apple website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ripped straight from the [Apple Dev site](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html):

> **Xcode 4 Developer Preview Download Now Available**
>
> iOS Developer Program members log in to the [iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/)
>
> Mac Developer Program members log in to the [Mac Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/mac/)

---

You also have to be a member of the ($99/year) Mac Developer Program (as I mentioned in the comments below):
[image: mac dev thing]

Comment: I hear you and I saw it, the link doesn't take you anywhere you can download Xcode 4 preview. Instead you're brought to the member area where you can register for $99/year. If you don't, only Xcode 3.2.3 is available for download. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ron M.: you also have to be a member of the [Mac Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/), which is different from registering on the Apple website. It costs $99/year. Once you log in to the Dev Center, scroll down near the bottom, and you'll see the bit that says: **Xcode 4 Developer Preview**
Mac Developer Programs members can download the preview today.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to register at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) before you can download the preview. From there, it's in the Mac Dev Center.

Comment: we're talking about the $99/year account, not just Registering as a Mac/iOS developer, right?

Comment: You just need to register as a developer. It's free.

Comment: But will the Xcode 4 preview be available for those who are not paid members?

Comment: Like I said, it's free. You don't need to pay anything.

Answer (score 0):

The preview isn't available anymore. You can either buy it from the Mac store for $4 or enlist as developer for 99$/year and get it free.

The older xcode 3.2.6 is still available for free.